# namespace issue in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following structure.

```
app/
  acme/
    Providers/
    Services/
      CloudServices/
        Files/
          FielsInterface.php
          s3Files.php
      Images/
        ImageEditorInterface.php
         ImageEditor.php
```

I am using s3files through its binding in a controller by adding

```
use Acme\Services\CloudServices\Files\FilesInterface
```

to the top of the controller and then using the constructor and it works great.

I now want to use it within ImageEditor.php whose namespace is

```
Acme\Services\Images
```

but with the following code I get a type error saying argument two must be an instance of FilesInterface but none given

```
<?php namespace Acme\Services\Images;

use IntImage;
use Response;
use Acme\Services\CloudServices\Files\FilesInterface;

/**
*
*/
class ImageEditor implements ImageEditorInterface
{
    protected $imageeditor;
    protected $files;
    protected $imageSizes = array(
        "thumbnail" => array(
            "h" => 50,
            "w" => 50
        ),
        "x-small" => array(
            "h" => 150,
            "w" => 150
        ),
        "small" => array(
            "h" => 390,
            "w" => 360
        )
    );

    public function __construct(IntImage $imageeditor, FilesInterface $files)
    {
        $this->imageeditor = $imageeditor;
        $this->files = $files;
    }
```

Seen as it works in the controller I am guessing that my use statement is wrong but I have no idea what it should be instead?

edit1:

ImageEditor is being injected and used in a controller like so

```
<?php

use Acme\Services\Images\ImageEditorInterface;
use Acme\Services\CloudServices\Files\FilesInterface;

class ImagesController extends BaseController
{
    protected $image;
    protected $editor;
    protected $files;
    protected $queue;

    public function __construct(Image $image, ImageEditorInterface $editor, FilesInterface $files, Queue $queue)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
        $this->editor = $editor;
        $this->files = $files;
        $this->queue = $queue;
        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => array('show')));
    }
public function store()
{
    $this->editor->createUserImages()

}
```

edit2: in Acme/Providers/FilesServiceProvider.php I have, isn't that doing what you describe? Also as I can use the files implementation in the controller wouldn't it suggest that that part is set up correctly?

```
<?php namespace TrainerCompare\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use TrainerCompare\Services\CloudServices\Files\S3Files;
use AWS;

/**
*
*/
class FilesServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('TrainerCompare\Services\CloudServices\Files\FilesInterface', function () {
            $aws = new AWS;

            return new S3Files($aws);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How and where are you instantiating your ImageEditor?

Comment: Please check my edit I think I have added the info you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in you application you need to tell Laravel what concrete class to instantiate when it needs to inject a FilesInterface.

```
App::bind(
    'Acme\Services\CloudServices\Files\FilesInterface', 
    'Acme\Services\CloudServices\Files\s3Files'
);
```

You are probably addin the service provider to your `app/config/app.php` too, right?

So, as you are already binding it, to debug, check if it is actually bound:

```
Route::any('test', function()
{
    dd( App::bound('TrainerCompare\Services\CloudServices\Files\FilesInterface') );
});
```

Because looks like Laravel is not being able to find that binding at the time of the controller instantiation.

And check if your service provider register method is being called:

```
class FilesServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        dd('yes it is');

        ....
    }
}
```

EDIT:

There's probably a naming problem somewhere I can't see from here, but Laravel is looking for something not listed (as is) in the container. Things you may need to check: your files namespaces, your autoloading rules, and you can try to do tests by temporarily removing your uses and adding them directly to the controller

```
public function __construct(
    Image $image, ImageEditorInterface $editor,
    TrainerCompare\Services\CloudServices\Files\FilesInterface $files, 
    Queue $queue
)
{ ... }
```

Comment: test route returns true and yes it is is dumped if added to the method

Comment: I just noticed another issue in the same file that may or may not be related.  IntImage is the Intervention/Image package with laravel support and I changed the facade name to IntImage due to a conflict.  In InterfentionImageEditor I can call IntImage::make() no problem but if I inject it through the constructor as show above I get a method not found error.

Comment: Pretty odd. Edited to add some more info and another empiric test. :/

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time I guess I have some digging to do.  Adding directly to the constructor returns the same 'must be an instance of' error

Answer (score -2):

You’ll need to prepend your `use` statement with a backslash in your name-spaced class like so:

```
<?php namespace Acme\Services\Images;

use \Acme\Services\CloudServices\Files\FilesInterface;
```

Otherwise PHP will treat it as a relative namespace path and try and resolve it as thus:

`Acme\Services\Images\Acme\Services\CloudServices\Files\FilesInterface`

Comment: Use clauses are allways taken from root.

Comment: Not in my experience.

Comment: Then you're having some weird experiences, maybe put down the dope. ;o) `use` namespaces are indeed always *fully qualified*, not relative to the current namespace.